# Loading and displaying svg

Tags: javascript, html, svg, fabricjs

how do you load a .svg into a fabricjs.html page?

my fabric [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X7tV8/) attempts to load a http .svg file, but I have, of course, tried local versions. I have used .svg files generated from adobe illustrator and fabric itself.

```
fabric.loadSVGFromURL( gvs_svgSrc, 
                       function ( argo ) 
                         { //alert( "load handler : " + argo ) ; 
                           // ... returns: #<fabric.Rect>
                           lvo_SVG = argo.set({ left: 250, top: 200, angle: 0 });
                           lvo_SVG = argo.scale(0.25);
                           gvo_canvas.add( lvo_SVG );
                           gvo_canvas.renderAll();
                         });
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Here's how you load SVG from an external .svg**

Here's code (be sure you link to your own fabricJS .js):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fabric.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border: 1px solid red; }
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){

        var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
        var group = [];

        fabric.loadSVGFromURL("http://fabricjs.com/assets/1.svg",function(objects,options) {

            var loadedObjects = new fabric.Group(group);

            loadedObjects.set({
                    left: 100,
                    top: 100,
                    width:175,
                    height:175
            });

            canvas.add(loadedObjects);
            canvas.renderAll();

        },function(item, object) {
                object.set('id',item.getAttribute('id'));
                group.push(object);
        });


    }); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: __new fabric.Group(group)__  seems to be what I was missing ... thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
fabric.loadSVGFromURL('http://example.com/_bg.svg',function(objects, options){
  var svgData = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
  svgData.top = 30;
  svgData.left = 50;
  canvas.add(svgData);
});
```

1. Load .svg file in canvas from a valid .svg URL using fabric
2. Load svg file in canvas trough fabric

Comment: It is noteworthy that the difference between these two approaches/answers is that the first one extracts elements out of the SVG, i.e. trims the whitespace around. This approach does not trim any whitespace, which helped me in my case. Thanks